# Exception from a finished function: Error: 10 ABORTED: The referenced transaction has expired or is no longer valid

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to use transaction function to create/update documents in Firestore Database, but when the function is executed it will abort with error code above.
Here is my code, I cannot figure out what causes this.
By loggers I put in the code, they show only to this line `functions.logger.log("target: ", target);`

Thank you

````
  .document("chatrooms/{chatRoomId}/message/{messageId}")
  .onCreate((snap, context) => {
    db.doc(`chatrooms/${context.params.chatRoomId}`)
      .get()
      .then((parentData) => {
        functions.logger.log("data: ", parentData.data());
        if (parentData.data().member.length > 0) {
          db.runTransaction((transaction) => {
            parentData.data().member.map((target) => {
              functions.logger.log("target: ", target);
              const TrRef = db.doc(
                `userDetail/${target}/chatmessage/${context.params.chatRoomId}`
              );
              return transaction.get(TrRef).then((trDoc) => {
                if (!trDoc.empty) {
                  functions.logger.log("have record");
                  let readed = false;
                  if (snap.data().senderId == target) {
                    readed = true;
                  }
                  transaction.update(
                    db.doc(
                      `userDetail/${target}/chatmessage/${context.params.chatRoomId}`
                    ),
                    {
                      lastmsg: snap.data().text,
                      sender: snap.data().sender,
                      senderId: snap.data().senderId,
                      timestamp: snap.data().timestamp,
                      readed: readed,
                    }
                  );
                } else {
                  functions.logger.log("not have record");
                  let readed = false;
                  if (snap.data().senderId == target) {
                    readed = true;
                  }
                  if (
                    parentData.data().type == "private" ||
                    parentData.data().type == "chara"
                  ) {
                    transaction.set(
                      db.doc(
                        `userDetail/${target}/chatmessage/${context.params.chatRoomId}`
                      ),
                      {
                        lastmsg: snap.data().text,
                        sender: snap.data().sender,
                        senderId: snap.data().senderId,
                        timestamp: snap.data().timestamp,
                        readed: readed,
                        type: parentData.data().type,
                      }
                    );
                  } else {
                    transaction.set(
                      db.doc(
                        `userDetail/${target}/chatmessage/${context.params.chatRoomId}`
                      ),
                      {
                        thumbnail: parentData.data().thumbnail,
                        name: parentData.data().name,
                        lastmsg: snap.data().text,
                        sender: snap.data().sender,
                        senderId: snap.data().senderId,
                        timestamp: snap.data().timestamp,
                        readed: readed,
                        type: parentData.data().type,
                      }
                    );
                  }
                }
              });
            });
            return Promise.resolve();
          }).then();
        }
      });
  });```
````

Comment: The function is terminating before the transaction is complete. Transactions are asynchronous just like any other database operation.  Use the promise returned.

Comment: Sorry sir, but I have no clue. I've used read and create operations before but they work perfectly. So I didn't figure out where to return promise.